# Moving common config from csproj to Directory.Build.props

Tags: .net, .net-core, msbuild, csproj

Directory structure:

```
Directory.Build.props
src/
  Directory.Build.props
  Project1/
test/
  Directory.Build.props
  Project1.Tests/
    Project1.Tests.csproj
```

Parent `/Directory.Build.props`:

```xml
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Child `/test/Project1.Tests/Directory.Build.props`:

```xml
<Project>
  <Import Project="$([MSBuild]::GetPathOfFileAbove('Directory.Build.props', '$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)../'))" />
  <Sdk Name="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.10.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

`Project1.Tests.csproj`:

```xml
<Project>
</Project>
```

This doesn't work, and gives this error:

> src/test/Project1.Tests/Project1.Tests.csproj : error MSB4040: There is no target in the project.

It works when I change `Project1.Tests.csproj`:

```xml
<Project>
  <Sdk Name="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.10.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

How can I keep those bits in the `Directory.Build.props` instead of the `Project1.Tests.csproj`? This is a simple example, but I also have `Project2`, `Project3`, etc. - so I want to keep common config in one place.